# Is there a way to get guild id via discord invite?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Is there a way to get guild id via discord invite?

I wanna make a bot for blacklisting servers, but joining the server first and then checking if it's blacklisted is kinda backward.

Answer (score 2):

You can fetch the invite using [`Client.fetch_invite`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.fetch_invite) and use the `guild` attribute

```py
invite_url = "https://discord.com/123123"
invite = await bot.fetch_invite(invite_url)

if invite.guild.id in blacklisted_guilds:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`invite = await bot.fetch_invite("https://discord.com/invitecode")`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=invite#discord.Client.fetch_invite) then from that you could get the guild by doing [`invite.guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=invite#discord.Invite)